# How to use a tag for input type submit

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<form>
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s"><?php _x( 'Search for:', 'label' ); ?></label>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search"/>
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button' ); ?>" />
</form>
```

how to use a tag for input type button. my a tag cod is:

```
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-search" ></a>
```

Comment: You can use a button and just style it with CSS. Or use some sort of javascript to do what that button should do.

Answer (score 1):

By default the submit uses the `form action` to redirect on submit.

```
<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="redirect.html">
  <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Clickable Button" />
</FORM>
```

OR

```
<!-- form here -->
<button type="submit" form="form2" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

If you want to just create a form which doesn't have action then you may use a `button` tag within `a` to link it.

OR you just want an input button which redirects:

```html
<form>
  <input type="button" onclick="parent.location='https://www.google.com/'" value="Google" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form id="form">
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">label</label>
    <input type="text" value="value" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search"/>
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="value" />
</form>

  <a href="#" class="fa fa-search" id="a-submit">Submit</a>

<script>
/*using jQuery*/
$(function() {
 $('#a-submit').on('click', function(){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#form').submit();
 });
});
</script>

or

<script>
/*Using native JavaScript*/
var element = document.querySelector("#a-submit");
element.onclick = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  document.querySelector("#form").submit();
};
</script>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.